# Can't alter size of BoxLayouts in ScrollView Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm having trouble spacing my `BoxLayouts` out on the below screen. I have to put `size_hint_y: None` for each of the `BoxLayouts` otherwise everything overlaps each other. However, I can't work out how to change the size so I have just set them all to `None` or `1`. The image is also overlapping the `MDTextField` first name.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (381, 470)
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class UserDetails(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [UserDetails(name="user_details")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "user_details"
        return self.sm
```

```
<UserDetails>
    name: "user_details"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        ScrollView:
            id: grid
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: layout
                padding: 15
                spacing: 15
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    MDLabel:
                        size_hint_y: 1
                        halign: "center"
                        text: "PERSONAL DETAILS"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: 1,0,0,1
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    AsyncImage:
                        source: "image.png"
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    cols: 1
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: 15
                    MDTextField:
                        id: first_name
                        hint_text: "First Name"
                    MDTextField:
                        id: last_name
                        hint_text: "Last Name"
                    MDTextField:
                        id: date_of_birth
                        hint_text: "Date of Birth"
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    MDCheckbox:
                        group: "gender"
                        id: male
                    MDCheckbox:
                        group: "gender"
                        id: female
                    MDCheckbox:
                        group: "gender"
                        id: unknown
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    cols: 1
                    Label:
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        pos_hint: {"top": 0.8}
                        md_bg_color: 1,0,0,1
                        text: "Submit"
                    Label:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `size_hint_y: None` and `height: self.minimum_height` for a `BoxLayout`, then the height of the `BoxLayout` is calculated by summing the `heights` of the children. A child with `size_hint_y: None` and no value set for `height` will get counted as `0` toward the minimum height of the `BoxLayout`. So you need to set `heights` for all the children.

Also, you have several case where you have a `Layout` with just one child. You can normally replace that arrangement with just the child.

Here is how I would modify your `kv`:

```
<UserDetails>
    name: "user_details"
    
    ScrollView:
        id: grid
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: layout
            padding: 15
            spacing: 15
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            MDLabel:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"
                text: "PERSONAL DETAILS"
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,0,0,1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
            AsyncImage:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 100
                source: "image.png"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols: 1
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: 15
                MDTextField:
                    id: first_name
                    hint_text: "First Name"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                MDTextField:
                    id: last_name
                    hint_text: "Last Name"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                MDTextField:
                    id: date_of_birth
                    hint_text: "Date of Birth"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 40
                MDCheckbox:
                    group: "gender"
                    id: male
                MDCheckbox:
                    group: "gender"
                    id: female
                MDCheckbox:
                    group: "gender"
                    id: unknown
            MDRaisedButton:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 40
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
                md_bg_color: 1,0,0,1
                text: "Submit"
```